# How can I loop through dates and store weight values in a matrix? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

Hi so I am new to MATLAB. I am trying to find the means of weight values for each month over five years and put these values into a matrix that will be 5x12 in size.

I am attempting to accomplish this with a loop but I'm having a little trouble, if anyone can push me towards the right direction that would be awesome, thanks. What I have so far is this:

```
weight_data = (10 weights per month for 10 years, 1200 weights total)
year = (years 2000-2010) %year 1-10 corresponds with the 1200 weights)
month = (months 1-12) %weights for all months (120 months, correspond with 1200 weights)

weight_vec = zeros([12, 5]);

     for n = year(1:5)
       weights = weight_data(n);
       mean_weights = mean(weights);
     end
```

This only gives me one number though, I assume the mean from the 5 years I'm trying to loop through. I also know I need to incorporate the months somehow but I'm just confused on how to do this.

Comment: How is `weight_data` defined? Is its size anything like `(weights x 12  x 10)`? In 5 years there are 60 months, why the output matrix should be `(60 x 5)`?

Comment: @il_raffa  1) There's 10 data points (weights) per month so 10 weights x 12 months x 10 years. 2) Woops, I meant (12x5) 12 months by 5 years, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Being your `weight_data` matrix `(10 weights x 12 months x 10 years)`, the weight of the `i-th` year are located in `weight_data(:,:,i)`.

```
w=weight_data(:,:,i)
```

`w` is a `(10 x 12)` which contains the 10 weights values of the 12 months.

You can use [mean](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) to compute the mean value of the weights of each month:

```
w=mean(weight_data(:,:,i))
```

Therefore you can setup a loop over the years:

```
for i=1:1:5
   mean_weights(:,i)=mean(weight_data(:,:,i))'
end
```

(the `'` in `mean(weight_data(:,:,i))'` is required to transpose the output of `mean` from a `row-array` to a `column-array` so that it fits in your output matrix which is `(12 x 5)`

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific; I have 3 vectors, one is weight_data = (1200 weights), month = (1200 months that correspond with the 1200 weights, year = (1200 years that correspond with the 1200 weights & thus the months as well).